# background gradient not rendering correcty in IE10

Tags: css, background, internet-explorer-10

```css
#top_container
{  
   padding-bottom: 5px;
   background: #d1d1ff;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#7db9e8), to(#1e5799));
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(#d1ffff, #d1d1ff);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(#d1ffff, #d1d1ff);
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#d1ffff, #d1d1ff);
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d1ffff', endColorstr='#d1d1ff',gradientType=0 );
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d1ffff 30%, #d1d1ff 100%);
   background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #d1ffff 30%, #d1d1ff 70%);
}
```

The gradient is being displayed correctly except in IE10 - I have searched for other possible versiuon of syntax to use and tried many different version of both the -ms-linear-gradient and linear-gradient.

What else could be cauisng this not to be displayed. The background #d1d1ff is being displyed in the container.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot how it is displayed correctly and incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/932wsed0/) built using [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). Lot's of tools online for this! Added a min-height so that it will display properly on jsFiddle make sure you remove that if you copy this code.

CSS:

```
#top_container {  
    min-height: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background: #d1ffff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #d1ffff 0%, #d1d1ff 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#d1ffff), color-stop(100%,#d1d1ff));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #d1ffff 0%,#d1d1ff 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #d1ffff 0%,#d1d1ff 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #d1ffff 0%,#d1d1ff 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #d1ffff 0%,#d1d1ff 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d1ffff', endColorstr='#d1d1ff',GradientType=0 );
}
```

Comment: I tried using JSfiddle -- the gradient still wouldn't render correcty

Comment: Hmm, that's odd, I've just tested this in IE10 on Win7 and it works just fine, both in jsFiddle and on a live page. Did you try copying my CSS over? Perhaps you have some value elsewhere that is overriding it - inspect the code in Chrome and see where the background color element is being set?

Comment: the top_container is being filled with #d1fff in IE10 - but with the gradient in chrome - Yes, I copied over the code, refreshed etc.

Comment: When you inspect the code in Chrome and look at the computed properties and then the background or background-color, where does it say that those properties are being set? Also, what standard is your IE using? (F12 -> there is a setting in here)

Comment: In chrome - it says the background-image is being  computed from top_container and points to the line in the css file. in IE it is in compt mode --  that was what I was loking for -- thanks!

Comment: EDIT: Ah nice, it was the browser/documents mode! Glad to resolve it.